# Change default function parametar

Tags: php

I have a function that saves images

```
public function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {
  if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
     imagejpeg($this->image, $filename, $compression);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

     imagegif($this->image, $filename);
  } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

     imagepng($this->image, $filename);
  }
  if( $permissions != null) {

     chmod($filename, $permissions);
  }
}
```

In this function the compression is 75.
Curently i am calling the function like this.

```
$simpleImage->save($tempImagePath . $tempImageName);
```

How can i pass the parametar in function call for compression to be 60, without changing it in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter is an optional parameter. However to use it, you must specify all the previous parameters (in your case you must pass `type of image` as well):

```
$type = IMAGETYPE_JPEG ;
$compression = 60 ;

$simpleImage->save($tempImagePath . $tempImageName, $type, $compression);
```

Or simply:

```
$simpleImage->save($tempImagePath . $tempImageName, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, 60);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was the problem, i had to pass the type as well.